# Can universe be a closed manifold?

Tags: spacetime, universe, differential-geometry, maxwell-equations

I had a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431126/laplace-beltrami-operator-on-sphere) at MSE which gave a rise to another question.

[Maxwell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Alternative_formulations) can be written in form $$d\star F = J$$

Then by Stokes theorem we have

$$ \int_U J = \int_U d \star F = \int_{\partial U} \star F.$$

If $U$(universe) is closed then $\partial U=\emptyset$ is empty. So $\int_U J=0$.

What does says about space time. Is it possible that $\int_U J=0$? Or is it proof that universe cannot be closed?

Comment: In a $4$ dimensional space-time $U$, $F$ and $*F$ are $2$-forms. So $d*F$ is a $3$-form. So writing $\int_U d \star F$ has no sense : How can you integrate a $3$-form, on a $4$ dimensional space-time ?

Comment: Ohh sorry there should be probably only a space.